# How to use WebRTC in GAE/J Project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twilio, opentok, tokbox

I want to start Video Session on a specific date and time between two users of my application.The Application is written in Java on Google App Engine.
I know about the Twilio SMS/Voice Services ,but GAE docs don't mention about how to have Video Calls.
I have looked into TOKBOX API, which seems a good fit, but what i want to know is , is there a better way to have a Scheduled Video Call in Google App Engine. Is there any bundled service i can use.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

TokBox has created a Starter Kit called [ScheduleKit](https://github.com/opentok/schedulekit-php) that has about the same purpose. The UI is modeled like a customer support application, and it also emails a reminder for the video chat. The sample code is built in PHP, but it can easily be ported to work with Java. Take a look at the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK).

Comment: I added OPENTok Java SDK to my Google App Engine Project and wrote the code to get a session ID,However When i try to run this code, i get run time errors pointing to missing dependency jarlike Jackson Jars,SL5j Jars,async Http Client etc.. Do i have to download all those dependency Jars to my project and then run it.If so where can i find list of dependencies?

Comment: only the runtime dependencies, not the compile time dependencies.  OPENTok should have a list somewhere. Maven should make it much, much easier.  My two cents, gradle build files.